# In T-SQL, how can I collate positive and negative actions in order that they happened?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES(1,'BlueCar',NULL),
              (2,'RedCar',NULL),
              (3,NULL,'BlueCar'),
              (4,'GreenCar',NULL),
              (5,NULL,'RedCar'),
              (6,'BlueCar',NULL)
        ) AS ValuesTable(Time,Buy,Sell)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE

Time Buy      Sell
1    BlueCar  NULL
2    RedCar   NULL
3    NULL     BlueCar
4    GreenCar NULL
5    NULL     RedCar
6    BlueCar  NULL
```

How can I query this table to get the total number of cars still in stock? The Time column is days since the shop opened. The time that the car was purchased must be preserved

Note: The input data is such that there will never be a situation where there are multiple cars in the inventory.

Expected Output

```
Time Buy
4    GreenCar
6    BlueCar
```

Comment: which database are you using??

Comment: What output would you want if the inventory had multiple cars left?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The input data is such that there will never be a situation where there are multiple cars left. Rams I have written a CTE with sample data

Comment: Then surely you just output those items which appear more times in the `Buy` column than they do in the `Sell` column - no need to process the items "in order"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's quite a smart take on the problem, I hadn't been able to reduce it to that in my mind. thank you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, ah i need to preserve the Time that the car in stock was purchased, so this method cannot work.

Comment: in Expected output, you required TIME column?

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale, yes, so the current answers dont suffice at the moment. i think it requires a recursive cte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `not exists`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES(1,'BlueCar',NULL),
              (2,'RedCar',NULL),
              (3,NULL,'BlueCar'),
              (4,'GreenCar',NULL),
              (5,NULL,'RedCar'),
              (6,'BlueCar',NULL)
        ) AS ValuesTable(Time,Buy,Sell)
)
SELECT
    [Time], Buy
FROM CTE as T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE as T2 WHERE T2.TIME > T1.TIME AND T1.Buy = T2.Sell) AND
    BUY IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: > in the where clause is giving me performance issues on large datasets. do you have time to suggest a workaround? thanks

Comment: @DannyRancher - Index should help: (Sell, Time)

Answer (score 2):

In the query below, I do two separate aggregations to obtain the buy and sell counts for each car.  I left join buys to sells, which should not run the risk of losing data assuming that the dealer did not short sell any inventory which does not actually exist.

Then I join that result to a CTE which finds the latest time for each car.  This would then correspond to the time when the most recent car came into inventory, for each car type.

I also include the inventory count, which you did request, but it may be useful for you if you decide to expand the scope of your query later on.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Time, 'BlueCar' AS Buy, NULL AS Sell UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'RedCar',NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,NULL,'BlueCar' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'GreenCar',NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,NULL,'RedCar' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'BlueCar',NULL
),
cte AS (
    SELECT Buy, Time
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Buy, Time,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Buy ORDER BY Time DESC) rn
        FROM yourTable
    ) t
    WHERE rn = 1
)

SELECT
    t1.Buy,
    t1.buy_cnt - COALESCE(t2.sell_cnt, 0) AS inventory,
    t3.Time
FROM
(
    SELECT Buy, COUNT(*) AS buy_cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Buy
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Sell, COUNT(*) AS sell_cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Sell
) t2
    ON t1.Buy = t2.Sell
LEFT JOIN cte t3
    ON t1.Buy = t3.Buy
WHERE
    t1.Buy IS NOT NULL AND
t1.buy_cnt - COALESCE(t2.sell_cnt, 0) > 0
ORDER BY
    t3.Time;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I clarified the question to include Expected Output and didn't want confusion regarding your answer as the best so far. sorry, I need the time that the remaining car was purchased

Comment: @DannyRancher I gave you a query which generates the output you want.  I even include the inventory count, despite that you always expect it to be 1.  Please remove the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

To get the stock at a certain point in time you can do

```
SELECT car, SUM(Inc) total FROM
 (SELECT ID, Buy car,   1 Inc FROM tbl WHERE Buy>''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Sell car, -1 Inc FROM tbl WHERE Sell>'') coll
WHERE ID < 20  -- some cut-off time
GROUP BY car
```

I combine the two columns `Buy` and `Sell` into one (= `car`) and add another column (`inc`) with the increment of each action (-1 or 1). The rest is simple: `select` with a `group by` [car] and summation over column `inc`.

Here is a little demo: http://rextester.com/LLQDW60692

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want:

```
with cte as (
      . . . 
     )
select count(buy) - count(sell)
from cte;
```

Note:  This does not verify that what you sell is something that has already been bought.  It just counts up the non-`NULL` values in each column and takes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is Good Question. I like that. Time by time your expected outputs changes.Its ok.
check below simple query for your problem.
Using Joins and Rownumber() we can achieve this.

```
 ;with CTE as
 (
   select a.time,a.buy,a.rid,COALESCE(b.rid,0)rid2 ,coalesce(b.sell,a.buy)sell from 
   ( select time,buy,ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by buy order by (select 1)) rid  
    from #tableName where buy is not null)a left join 
   ( select time,sell, ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by sell order by (select 1)) rid
    from #TableName
      where sell is not null )b on a.buy=b.sell   
  )
  select Time,Buy from CTE
  where rid!=rid2
```

Sample Demo For All Your Expected outputs.
[Demo Link](http://rextester.com/ULD8700) : [Click Here](http://rextester.com/ULD8700)

> ALL Required Outputs :

[image]